# Delete row with the use of Max(Date)?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to delete some members from their table based on their rental date. If they havent rented for more than 3 years they can be deleted. The issue i am facing is that some members have rented recently, meaning the query still pulls their ID up and deletes ALL data because there is a date on their record indicating the DateOut value of greater than 3 years.

```
delete from (select *
               from rental
                    inner join member
                            on rental.member_id = member.member_id
                    inner join rental_line
                            on rental.rental_id = rental_line.rental_id
              where months_between(sysdate, dateout) > ( 36 )); 

delete from member
 where exists(select dateout
                from rental
               where member.member_id = rental.member_id
                 and months_between(sysdate, rental.dateout) > ( 36 ));
```

These are the two scripts i am running to delete the data, it is pulled out from rental first and their is a ON CASCADE within the foreign key which also pulls the data from the Rental_Line table.
Then the second query runs to delete the data from the member table freely as there isn't any integrity issues due to the corresponding data being removed previously from the linked tables.

Comment: You mentioned there are tenants whose ID is recently updated. So what's the issue? Can you,show the table schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Delete from rental r where r.member_id in (
  select i.member_id 
  from rental i 
  group by i.member_id 
  having MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, max(dateout))>(36)
);

DELETE FROM Member where not exists(
  Select * 
  from rental 
  where Member.Member_ID =  Rental.Member_ID
);
```

You just finished deleting all of the rental records, unless you keep an archive, you are just looking for members without rentals at all. If this is not the case, you will need to make a temporary holding table for member_id's that were purged.